# Multiple threads on MyISAM table

Tags: mysql, sql, benchmarking, mariadb

I was trying to perform a benchmark on my MariaDB10.0.14 to read data on MyISAM table using multiple threads and i kept on getting an exception to do with duplicate entry for primary key. Does MyISAM support reading using multiple threads? I am using sysbench for benchmarking, and my config are as follows:

```
Prepare testing dataset
#sysbench --test=/usr/share/doc/sysbench/tests/db/oltp.lua --mysql-table-engine=myisam 
--oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-db=sbread --mysql-user=testdb --mysql-password=testpw
--mysql-socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock prepare


Reads
#sysbench --num-threads=1 --max-requests=500000 --test=/usr/share/doc/sysbench/tests/
db/oltp.lua -- oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 
--oltp-read-only --mysql-db=sbread --mysql-user=testdb --mysql-password=testpw run
```

So the test db being created has MyISAM storage engine for its tables as you can see in the "Prepare testing dataset. When i try to read with a single thread, it runs fine. But when i try to access the db with multiple threads (--num-threads=16) for example, that is when i get the following error:

```
ALERT: mysql_drv_query() for query 'INSERT INTO sbtest1 (id, k, c, pad) VALUES (498360, 567750, 
'84578502161-76498916585-15177095459-91229149818-13877895508-00429671145-18341319379-39103937662-
51579802230-43663801413', '79741072395-37018170150-53859605676-72598517156-41247843127')' failed: 
1062 Duplicate entry '498360' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: My MariaDB run this sysbench without any error.  Please post your complete errormessage.

Comment: Hi Julina. I have edited my post to include more detail. I have also included the sysbench commands i used to prepare the test db and also to run the "read" test. I am not sure why the error mentions insertion because this should be a "read only" test as defined by the --oltp-read-only expression in the test command.

Answer (score 0):

You are using --oltp-read-only instead of --oltp-read-only=on, thus you're not running the expected read-only benchmark.